# Formato correcto de URL's dinámicas en objetivos con funnel de Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Escribo porque he probado todo lo posible para configurar un **objetivo con funnel en Google Analytics**, para un proceso de compra, en una tienda online, realizada en **woocommerce**, pero no sé por qué pero no me funciona.

A continuación, muestro los diferentes pasos y la URLs. Los 3 primeros pasos tienen **URL dinámicas**:

Ejemplos de **url reales** de los 3 primeros pasos:

1. /productos/?type=web-boda
2. /producto/cactus-collection/
3. /producto/cactus-collection/packs/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observando los resultados de **la grafica del embudo**, al cabo de unos días, veo que no hay ningún usuario que pasa **a través de los pasos 1,2 y 3**. La conclusión que saco es que las expresiones regulares están mal.

Para comprobar que la expresión regular no es correcta, **utilizo el buscador** como muestro en la siguiente imagen. Y cual es mi sorpresa que coincide con algunas de las URL reales que hay en mi web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A parte, **el grafico de embudo muestra estas URL**, pero no la hace pasar por el paso packs del funnel. Las indica como si accedieran directamente  al paso carrito.

A alguien se le ocurre alguna solución para probar ya que me he quedado estancado .

Comment: Pregunto desde la ignorancia de cómo funciona el funnel... El problema es que no entra en "Packs", pero va a "Carrito" (como mencionaste), o en realidad va a "Producto"??? ...La sintaxis de las expresiones está bien... asumo que es un tema de orden de reglas o que tengas que limitarlas un poco.

Comment: El problema es que no entra en ninguno de los 3 pasos iniciales y se añade directamente a carrito. Pero como dices, la expresión me parece correcta y no entiendo porque no entra en ningun paso.

Comment: Estoy documentandome, ya que no conozco nada de funnel, sólo de regex.... ¿Seleccionaste "Regular Expressions" en el dropdown de **Destination**?

Answer (score 2):

Un error muy habitual es no configurar el tipo de coincidencia en el campo **`Destino`**.

No es tan claro visualmente, pero para que se apliquen expresiones regulares en todos los pasos, dentro del campo <kbd>Destino</kbd> se debe seleccionar <kbd>Expresión Regular</kbd>. Y este tipo de coincidencia va a aplicar tanto al destino como a cada uno de los pasos.

[image: Destination: Regular Expression]

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano. Pues seguramente he caido en el error que comentabas. Pensaba que podía utliizar en la parte superior el "Empieza por" y en la parte inferior las expresiones regulares. Esperaré un par de días que almacene resultados y comento si con esto todo va bien. Lo dicho, mil gracias!

Comment: @Marcvilap me alegro que sea eso, más aún que jamás lo había usado ;-)

Comment: Una pregunta @Mariano y si mi expresión regular no es el destino? o sea si es parte de los pasos? no es necesario activar eso verdad?

Comment: ah ok he leido bien para que funcione tanto en los pasos como en el destino tengo que activar la expresión regular si o si :)